How to use an electronic load to test a square wave output?
I want to load test the output of a motor driver. The first test is a square wave where the wave is actually contains data. The square wave can have a "1" width and a "0" width, so it is more like a pulse train of 8-10kHz depending on the sequence of 1s and 0s. The real world load is a circuit that starts with a bridge rectifier and picks power and signal off of the wave. The second test would send a DC PWM signal of set frequency of 400Hz or less, and duty cycle from 0 to 100%, so is really just pulsed DC. That goes directly to a DC motor in the actual circuit. Voltages can be between 12 and 18V, current maxed at about 5A. I care about looking at a particular current and then testing how hot components get.
For the square wave, I was just going to connect a bridge rectifier in between the motor driver and a cheap DC electronic load. I am assuming at 12V, I would have an output from the rectifier of around 11V with small dips of maybe 1V at twice my input frequency to account for the transitions between each set of diodes in the bridge. Is this an acceptable way to test? Is there anything I should be aware of in advance?
For the PWM test, I was going to connect directly to the electronic load. Am I right to assume that whether it is DC or pulsed DC of somewhere between 80 and 400Hz is no problem for an electronic load? I'm assuming it would just turn the internal MOSFET(s) on and off at that frequency but am not sure how these boxes handle the constant current or constant power modes and making sure I am getting accurate current readings.

What does the spec sheet for the electronic load say?

The problem with stuff from China is there are almost never specs. This is one I was looking at https://a.co/d/6Bsphel

@FDecker that's why EEs buy stuff from a reputable supplier who uses quality sources and, why EEs don't use stuff that doesn't have a proper data sheet.

Tens of thousands of EEs buy DL24P's, KP184's, or ET5410A+. Not being familiar with e-loads, I thought someone with experience could say whether these would work with the signals I mentioned or not. If there is a particular spec I can find and report, just let me know. Posting a schematic after further research

Looking at the electronic load schematic:
It's a MOSFET constant current sink, so you can expect reasonable bandwidth in constant current mode.
For the other settings like constant power or resistor emulation, it measures input voltage with a smartmeter chip sigma delta ACD which probably operates at around 60 samples per second according to the "4800bps" on the UART lines... (2 samples, 4 bytes per sample). Then it will use the microcontroller to set the constant current sink to the desired value according to input voltage.
So it's probably going to be very very slow to react to input voltage changes. Not a problem if you use it with DC, it would be fine to test a battery, but for a square wave, it'll probably react to average voltage.
Now, driving it with a square wave with your motor controller... since you mention using PWM, at some point in the square wave the voltage will be zero.
If the input voltage is too low so the MOSFET can't pass the desired current, the opamp driving the MOSFET will clip to the positive rail in an attempt to drive it some more. Then when input voltage comes back your motor controller will look into a load that's basically a fully ON IRFP260 (55 mOhms) plus two Swhottky diodes in parallel (negligible dynamic resistance). So a huge current will flow, until the LM321 driving the MOSFET reacts and corrects the gate voltage. This should take a while, because it's a very slow opamp with a large cap in the feedback.
Also the MOSFET has a large Cgd and is driven through a 1k resistor, so there is a large current spike due to Miller effect when input voltage is applied.

This current spike will occur at every turn-on of your H-bridge, so it's probably not going to last very long.

There are 2 modes for the device to load test. 1. Square wave varying between 8-10kHz. 2. PWM signal I can keep at 50% or more duty cycle. Do I need to rectify the square wave first? The reverse voltage diode will already half-wave rectify it, but if I rectify it for #1, remove the rectifier for #2 and change it to 100% duty cycle PWM, I should have the same DC voltage in both cases (minus the drop and crossing glitches in the rectifier in #1). Correct? I just need to see how hot the test unit gets at 3-5A and measure the current through it with 10mA or better accuracy. Thank you!

It won't work with the electronic load, use a resistor

Last clarification about what I am missing. So rectifying the square wave for test 1 and setting the separate PWM test to 100% duty cycle is not good enough? That effectively makes both tests DC that the constant current mode of the load would see, no? Finding/making 3, 3.5, 4, 4.67 Ohm resistors, at 60W or more is a challenge also.

At DC it will work, but if you use any other value than 100% PWM, the load will draw large current spikes at each turn on which will be dangerous for your MOSFETs. If you need good cheap high power resistors... 12V halogen lightbulbs. The resistance varies a lot with temperature though, so it's not accurate at all, but if you want to dump a lot of power into a cheap test load it's hard to beat... there's also resistive wire from the closest e-cigarette shop!
